# Ошибка при подключении враппера и библиотеки, написанной на С, в коде на C#

Tags: c, c#

Скачал с  [сайта](http://www.sdss.jhu.edu/~tamas/bytes/fftwcsharp.html) враппер
и скачал  [библиотеку](http://fftw.org/#documentation). Поместил dll враппер в папку с библиотекой, где лежат exe и неуправляемые dll и другие файлы библиотеки. Подключил dll враппер. Как я понял, враппер сам подключает библиотеку. Попробовал осуществить пример, на основе кода, предоставленного на первом сайте.

Но при первом же обращении к библиотеке

```
pin = fftwf.malloc(n*8);
```

вылезает ошибка:

> `Не удается загрузить DLL "libfftw3f-3.dll": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)`

Использовал  LoadLibrary, как написано в комментариях, но ничего не изменилось, ошибка все та же  появляется.

Как же правильно подключить враппер и библиотеку?

Comment: Разрядность либы какая? 32|64?

Comment: 32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true)]
static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string filename);

IntPtr handle = LoadLibrary(Path.GetFullPath(@"libfftw3f-3.dll"));

if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
{
    // TODO: Работа с библиотечными методами
}
else
{
    int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();

    // TODO: Обработка ошибки
}
```

Вообще часто еще бывает, что нативные библиотеки требуют дополнительных компонентов, которых нет на используемой машине, например, C Run-Time. Это можно проверить. Например, [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) - весьма удобная утилита для таких целей.

Comment: на Path.GetFullPath выдает ошибку:  Элемент "Path" не существует в текущем контексте.

Comment: Добавьте `using System.IO;` в секцию using.

Comment: а в каком случае будет выполняться:
handle != IntPtr.Zero   ?
а то у меня все время не выполняется это условие и библиотека поэтому не используется

Comment: `handle != IntPtr.Zero`, если библиотека успешно загрузилась. Если это не так, то надо смотреть код ошибки.

Comment: Ошибка все та же: Не удается загрузить DLL "libfftw3f-3.dll": Не найден указанный модуль. (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
Проверил с помощью Dependency Walker: появились проблемы с враппером (fftwlib.dll) 

Знаки вопросов у модулей(модуль не найден) IESHIMS.DLL и WER.DLL .

Розовый фон пиктограммы(предупреждение) у MPR.DLL

Warning: At least one delay-load dependency module was not found. Warning: At least one module has an unresolved import due to a missing export function in a delay-load dependent module.

Comment: А шансы найти её есть? (Или в %path%, или в текущей директории)

Answer (score 1):

В конце [этого топика на GotDotNet](http://www.gotdotnet.ru/forums/2/62172/) есть правильная последовательность действий. Смысл в том, что эта библиотека должна быть подгружена через WinAPI (kernel32.dll) функцию [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: а можно поподробнее как это будет выглядеть  в C#, а то я в этом почти ничего не понимаю.  
Почему в примере на первом сайте это не используется?